# what's the benefit of using mongoid (over ActiveRecord) as a backend for delayed jobs?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, delayed-job

Is there any benefit to using delayed_job_mongoid (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid) over an ActiveRecord backend for delayed jobs?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [ActiveRecord backend](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record) and I'm fine with it, but the load on our apps isn't enormous. I guess the biggest advantage to use the MongoDB backend is obtained when the project infrastructure already includes MongoDB, so you don't have to manage another service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with performance you should actually look at other alternatives like `sidekiq` or `resque` for background jobs.